# sqlfunctions.checksum of linq object

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to figure out how to get the sql statement:

`select checksum_agg(checksum(*)) from Foo`

to work from linq. I can get the checksum of a single column, so long as I know the column name:

`SqlFunctions.ChecksumAggregate(Foo.Select(x => x.Id));`

But I would like to either be able to checksum the collection or at least checksum the columns individually without knowing the name(s).

Answer (score 0):

The query [SqlFunctions.ChecksumAggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd487151%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) takes is **the collection of values over which the checksum is computed. Null values are ignored.**

For example, `SqlFunctions.ChecksumAggregate(Foo.Select(x => x.Id));` will calculate for each row of the table Foo, for **all** non-Null columns, calculate the checksum **over** the `Id` field.

So the checksum will utilize all info of non-Null columns.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The argument is an 'IEnumerable<Nullable<int>>' and result of the select statement is what is getting the checksum. It is not computing the checksum for all the columns in Foo, it is getting the checksum for the enumerable of id's returned in the select statement.