# Using checksum index from linq to sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table with an index on a `nvarchar(MAX)`-column by using [`CHECKSUM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql) as a computed column.  SQL query can use this index by using a `WHERE`-clause with both the text value and its checksum.

How can a [linq-to-sql](/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql) query use this index?

I looked at [sqlfunctions.checksum of linq object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17949647/814206) and [How do I calculate a checksum on all columns in a row using LINQ and Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29547542/814206) and their answers, i.e [`SqlFunctions.Checksum("important")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.checksum?view=netframework-4.7#System_Data_Objects_SqlClient_SqlFunctions_Checksum_System_String_) for a checksum of a single value.
But `SqlFunctions.Checksum("important")` throws the exception:

> This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

(this behaviour is exactly as is documented in the documentation for `Checksum(string)`).

In [sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver) the table can be defined via:

```
CREATE TABLE [Tags](
    [TagId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Tag] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [TagHash] AS (checksum([Tag])) PERSISTED
 )
```

and the index via:

```
 CREATE INDEX [IX_Tags] ON [Tags] (
     [TagHash] ASC
 )
```

The following SQL query might use the index<sup>1</sup>:

```
SELECT * FROM [Tags]
WHERE [TagHash] = checksum('Important') AND
    [Tag] = 'Important'
```

This query expression attempt in [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad) [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) throws the `NotSupportedException`:

```
from tag in Tags
where SqlFunctions.Checksum("important") == tag.Hash &&
    "important" == tag.Tag
select tag
```

How can the above query be constructed in [link-to-sql](/questions/tagged/link-to-sql) without using [link-to-entities](/questions/tagged/link-to-entities) only constructs like [`SqlFunctions.Checksum(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.checksum?view=netframework-4.7#System_Data_Objects_SqlClient_SqlFunctions_Checksum_System_String_)?

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>It depends on the query optimizer.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify your database and change your Linq2Sql model then you can do this by creating your own sql function that wraps CheckSum. For example

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.MyCheckSum (@input NVarChar(max)) RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN   
   Declare @output int
   select @output = CheckSum(@input)
   return @output
End
```

You can then use this like.

```
from tag in Tags
where MyChecksum("important") == tag.Hash && "important" == tag.Tag
select tag
```

If you can't modify your database or model, you could have a workaround that works for your example, at the expense of another database hit, eg

```
int checkSum this dc.ExecuteQuery<int>("select Checksum('important')").Single(); 

from tag in Tags
where checkSum == tag.Hash &&   "important" == tag.Tag
select tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a generic wrapper around `CHECKSUM` (as [sgmoore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125759/sgmoore) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237846/814206)).

You can write an accessor function to access the table via the checksum index:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TagsByName(
     @key nvarchar(max))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT
    [TagId],
    [Tag],
    [TagHash]
FROM Tags
WHERE CHECKSUM(@key) = [TagHash] AND
    @key = [Tag];
```

Compared to [sgmoore's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125759/sgmoore) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237846/814206) this has the advantage that all [link-to-sql](/questions/tagged/link-to-sql)- and SQL-queries can access the table via the TVF and are insulated from using the index and the checksums.  The downside is that every checksum index construct requires its own TVF, whereas in [sgmoore's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125759/sgmoore) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237846/814206) a single TVF suffices.